# Check for duplicate then increment the duplicate value by 1

Tags: javascript

I want to check the duplicate then if match increment the value by 1, but if the input is 0 disregard it. I want to start the increment in 1 not on 0. The processed on checking the duplicate value was ok.

Now the problem is I don't want to increment if the value is 0 it will retain as 0 value, I want to start to increment on value 1.

```
getDuplicateHierarchy: function() {
    var $this = this;
    var input = []
    var match = false;

    $.each($('.duplicate'), function(index, value) {
             input.push(this.value);

        for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) 
        {
             for (j = 0; j < input.length; j++) 
             {
                  if(input[i] == input[j])
                  {
                       if( i != j)
                       {
                       match = true;
                       }
                  }
             }
        }

        if(match)
        {
             $(value).parent().append('<div class="validation-duplicateHierarchy-error">Duplicate.</div>');
             $this.isValidHierarchy = false;
        }
    });
    return $this.isValidHierarchy;
},
```

Comment: The `for` loop as well as the following `if` condition should be outside of the `$.each()` construct.

Comment: What environment is this running in? Do you have access to Set()? Are you up for using a lib like lodash?

Comment: While you have told us what you *want*, you haven't explained what the problem with your code is.

Comment: Now the problem is I don't want to increment if the value is 0 it will retain as 0 value and also an empty value, I want to start to increment on value 1.

Comment: I can't see how the code relates to what you're saying, but if you don't want to do anything on 0, try: `if (value == 0)`. If by increment you mean the loop, try: `for (var i = 1; i <= input.length; i++) `.